# Is $B$ countable or uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $B=\mathbb{Z}^{\{0,1\}}$, that is the set of all functions from the set $\{0,1\}$ to the integers. 
Is $B$ countable or uncountable? Prove your answer.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $B = \mathbb{Z}^{\{0,1\}}$. 
$\forall f \in B$, $f \leftrightarrow (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \implies f(0)=a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(1)=b \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ 
Surjectivity: $\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \,\, \exists f$ such that $f(0)=a$, $f(1)=b$ 
Injectivity: If $(a_1,b_1) = (a_2,b_2)$, then $a_1 = a_2$ and $b_1 = b_2$ where $f(0)=a_1$ and $f(1)=b_1$ $\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ 
$\therefore \, \exists$ bijection $f \leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. 
$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable by using the map $f((0,0))=1$, $f((1,0))=1$, $f((1,1))=2$, $f((0,1))=3$, and so on (this can be seen as spiraling the lattice points of $\mathbb{R}^2$) where $f:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. 
$\therefore B$ is countable. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This is a correct proof. I would prefer one with more words and fewer symbols.

Comment: Contrast $\{0,1\}^\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think your proof and conclusion are basically correct. Here are some suggested improvements:

1. You can write the bijection between $B$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ in this fashion: Define $\Phi:B\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by $$\Phi(f)=(f(0),f(1)).$$ It is a good habit to make your notations neat and readable.
2. For the proof of injectivity, strictly speaking, after you obtained $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$, you should say the function $f$ that is mapped to $(a_1,b_1)$ and the function $g$ mapped to $(a_2,b_2)$ coincide. The notation $\forall(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ does not make sense at all.

Generally speaking, you did a very nice proof.